# Meaning of "X" in VN5E010AH datasheet

Tags: datasheet

I guess I know the answers already, but the "X" in this table really confuses me:
[image]

Source: [VN5E010AH datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vn5e010ah.pdf).

Questions 1: Is it usual for "X" to be used for "yes" - to me, it might as well mean "no".

If we take all three pins individually:

- Regarding OUT: I don't intend to let the output floating, so I'll ignore that one.
- Regardin IN: this pin will be driven from a microcontroller, which means that the pin would be floating until the micro has completed booting.

Question 2: can I interpret "X" as meaning that I don't need a pulldown resistor to keep the pin down until the micro has booted?

- Regarding CS_DIS, ST has confirmed the meaning of "X" in the [chip user manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00061834-vipower-m05-and-m05enhanced-highside-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf), available from  the [VN5E010AH resource webpage](https://www.st.com/en/automotive-analog-and-power/vn5e010ah.html#resource). From page 8:

> If current sense disable function is not required, CS_DIS pin should be left open or connected to ground through a resistor (~10 kΩ). Direct connection to ground is not safe (ISO pulses clamped through CS_DIS pin can damage the device).

Am I just just overthinking it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:
Usually, "X" means "don't care". But in this case it means "yes". So, you can leave OUT, IN, and CS_DIS floating (i can't see why you would leave OUT floating, though), but not CS pin.

Question 2:
Datasheet is unclear about it. I would put pulldown to IN an CS_DIS pins to be sure of their state.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review the datasheet. Glad to see that I'm not the only one to see this as confusing. I just opened a support case with ST - I'll update with their reply.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the delay. I did ask ST, and got answers from them. Repeating the question, since it was worded slightly differently than the original one:

---

Hello,

I'm getting really confused by Table 2 in the VN5E010AH datasheet. The meaning of "X" isn't really clear - or really explained.

To be more specific:

Question 1: is it allowed to leave CS_DIS floating? If allowed, is the behavior the same as in your other recommended configuration - tied to ground through a 10K resistor?

I found an answer to these questions on page 8 of document UM1556, but a confirmation would be appreciated nonetheless.

Question 2: the IN pin will be driven by a microcontroller, meaning that it will be floating until its boot sequence has completed. Do I need to add a pull-down resistor, or does the VN5E010AH has circuitry to prevent the input from being floating? If the VN5E010AH allows a floating IN pin, how does it behave - ON or OFF?

Both of these can be addressed by adding resistors, but I'd rather not have them if they're not required.

Full disclosure: these questions were already asked here: [Meaning of "X" in VN5E010AH datasheet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507182)

Feel very free to reply there should you prefer to do so. Assuming that you reply to this case instead of on E.S.O, I do plan to copy your reply there - unless you specifically ask me not to.

Thank you!

---

Hello,

Verified with Engineering:

1. The 'X' means "Don't Care"
2. Although pull-down resistors are allowed, it is not advisable.
   Best Regards ST Support

---

Hello,

Here is some additional input to your questions:

1. You can leave CS_DIS floating. It will pull to ground and not disable the CS pin. In electrically noisy environments I suggest a 10k to ground anyway. Floating inputs are just not a good idea.
2. Really, it can “float” to ground as it has a weak pull-down, the same as the CS_DIS pin. However, it is definitely not advisable for an input that controls the output. A 10k pull-down AT THE MICRO is strongly suggested. I emphasize at the micro in that at the HSD would cause resistor division reducing the effective input voltage.
   Best Regards ST Support

---

... in other words, they confirm [Morris's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/507192/117546), and "X" means "you can, but you shouldn't" - so I'm accepting his answer.